# Unable to display file content-php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am not able to display the content of the text file within the same webpage.The code is below (called display.php file)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png">
<body>
<?php
    $selectedfile = @$_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];
    $content = file($selectedfile);
    $data = implode("<br>",$content);
    echo $data;

?>
<?php
$dirname = "<directory to be scanned for files>";
$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<form name="displayfile" action="output.php" method="POST">';
echo '<select name="file_to_be_displayed">';
echo '<option value="">Select File</option>';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
        {
           if((($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and (($file != "store_show_commands_switches.tcl" and $file != "switches.txt"))and (($file != "store_show_commands_routers.tcl" and $file != "routers.txt"))and (($file != "store_show_commands_firewalls.tcl" and $file != "firewalls.txt"))))             
        {
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
                }
        }
                echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="display content of file" />';
echo '</form>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

output.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$myFile =$_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];
$file = file_get_contents ("$myFile"); 
Echo $file; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The display.php will scan the txt files within the directory and display them within a dropdown menu with a button next to it to display file selected. However, once I click the button I get a blank page with no result(it should display the content of the txt file)

Is there a way to fix this or -even better- is there a way to display the content of the file within the same display.php (I think it can be done with ajax but not sure how)

Thanks
Pantelis

Comment: Try `echo $myFile;` instead.

Comment: didn't do it I am afraid. Still displaying nothing on the webpage

Comment: Then try `$myFile = $selectedfile;` in your `output.php` file

Comment: didn't work either. I can get the filename (well sort of) by just having the following code

echo $_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];

However, the filename is not complete

Comment: how do you specify $dirname in output.php
it only knows filename but not the directory where it can be found

Comment: I'm going to try and test this. But in the meantime, try changing your `and` to `&&` in your `if((($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and....`

Comment: @Pantelis Try this `echo "<option value='$dirname$file'>$file</option>";` however the output may produce unexpected results. You had double quotes inside and I added `$dirname` next to `$file` which "kind of" worked.

Comment: No results as well. Do I need to redefine the $dirname as @webdevbyjoss suggested?

Comment: @Pantelis Run your codes from the root of your server, then if you have a folder called `test` for example, then set this like `$dirname = "test/";` the `/` at the end is important.

Comment: I am getting the error below

output.php: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
output.php: line 1: `<html>'

Comment: @Pantelis Is your `output.php` file exactly as you shown it here? Or do you have anything above it? Also try testing with just `if(($file != ".") && ($file != ".."))`

Comment: exactly as it's shown there. I am getting the same error (regarding html) if I run display.php as well from the server cli as root

Comment: @Pantelis I don't know what else it could be. It did work for "me", but the results weren't as expected, but results nonetheless.

Comment: @Fred -ii-, I have changed the output.php code to the following and it seems that when I click the button the URL is: output.php?file_to_be_displayed=routers.txt instead of the full path

`<html>
<body>
<?php 
$myFile =$_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];
$dirname = "/tmp/";
$file = "$dirname . "/".$file"; //Path to your *.txt file
$contents = file($file); 
$string = implode($contents); 
echo $string; 
?>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @Pantelis You'll probably need to use the full path for `$dirname` for example `/home/pantelis/public_html/tmp/` or try removing the last `/` in `/tmp/` as in `tmp/` since you have `$file = "$dirname . "/".$file";`

Comment: Hi @– Fred -ii- I've managed to fix the issue and it displays the file properly. The problem I have is that it doesn't display txt files with spaces within the filename. Could you please review and let me know if there is a way to include this? 

`<?php 

$myFile =$_POST['file_to_be_displayed'];

$myFile1 ="http://<path>"."$myFile";

echo $myFile1;

$lines = file("$myFile1");

$fileString = file_get_contents("$myFile1");

echo nl2br( htmlspecialchars($fileString) );

echo '<br>';

?>`

not sure how to add the above as code.sorry

Comment: I've replaced the zero within my tcl script and works fine. Thanks for all the help @– Fred -ii-